# Java daemon deployment infrastructure

Tags: java, deployment, daemon

Is there any deployment platforms for Java daemons? We have glassfish, geronimo etc. for web-application deployment, but if I have simple Spring based application which is processing messages from ActiveMQ or something like that. Where I should deploy that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are looking for something like [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html). I used it a couple of years ago for a group of services that needed a watchdog and start, stop and restart operations. You can do that and a few things more:

- **Run a Java application as a Windows Service or Unix Daemon:**
  makes it possible to install a Java Application as a Windows Service or a daemon process on Unix systems.
- **Standard, Out of the Box Scripting:** provides scripts for run on Windows and Unix
- **On Demand Restarts:** Your application can request a restart of their own JVM
- **Flexible Configuration:** Configuration for JVM and application can be centralized in a text file.
- **Logging:** While the Java Service Wrapper does not attempt to replace any Logging Tools available, it does provide a number of properties to configure how "stdout" and "stderr" output to the JVM console is handled. This output can be logged to any combination of the console, a file, or the "Event Log" (Windows) or "syslog" (Unix).

If you build your project with Maven, there is a [Application Assembler Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html) that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a simple daemon process with Spring](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=59253)

Comment: I know that. My question is there are some sort of application server but for plain java applications?

Comment: @dotsid no application server is needed... you can jar it up into a lib and write a servlet so it can be deployed on an app server, but it is not necessary